# Add all natural numbers that are multiples of 3 and 5 : What is the bug in the following code

Tags: c#

I know that this can be easily done by using

```
if(i%5 == 0 OR i%3 ==0) sum+=i;
```

But what is wrong in the following C#code:

```
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 1000; i+=3, j+=5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i = " + i);
        Console.WriteLine("j = " + j);

        sum += i;

        Console.WriteLine("Sum after adding i  = " + sum);

        if(j < 995 && j % 3 != 0)
        {
            sum += j;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sum after adding j  = " + sum);

    }
```

Comment: Sorry about this. Did you initialize sum to 0?

Comment: @wefwfwefwe you can start from anywhere. Would appreciate ANY feedback

Comment: You should always start at the first bug. Here that is the for loop.

Comment: @starblue what is the bug wrong with the loop?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the inclusion-exclusion principle. You sum some numbers twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement `j < 995` should probably be `j <= 995`, otherwise you are not going to add 995 to your sum.

Comment: yes. That is the issue. I should have figured it out myself. Thanks.

Comment: j < 1000 would be a little more pure

Answer (score 1):

The obvious bug is that 995 is a multiple of 5 that won't get added, while 996 and 999 are multiples of 3 that will be added: the 1000 in the loop condition and the 995 in the if condition should be the same number.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to sum all such natural numbers less than 1000, why excluding 995? You could put

```
j <= 995 && j%3!=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a nit-pick, maybe, but still: "All" and "lower than 1,000" is not the same set of natural numbers, you might want to change something.

Comment: " it risks adding the same number more than once" . How?

Comment: It doesn't, unwind is wrong about that. Your checks are sufficient to prevent adding the same number multiple times (although your loop design is unorthodox and a little confusing at first read).

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 15; i+=3, j+=5)
```

change this to

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i <= 15; i+=3, j+=5)
```

using the `<=` (greater than or equal to operator)

and it works